# Phonegap on iPhone 4 device

Tags: ios4, cordova

I have a PhoneGap app that works perfectly on the iPhone 3.2 simulator and also iPhone 3 and 3GS devices.

I have just downloaded and installed the latest iOS SDK, changed the settings in Project>Edit Project Settings to allow the application to work, and run it successfully within the iPhone 4 simulator and even the iPad simulator.

However when I run it on a provisioned iPhone 4 device, nothing seems to happen when I run it. I get the splash screen, but nothing happens after that. In the log I get this:-

2010-09-13 10:11:34.156 MyApp[89:307] Going to play default movie
2010-09-13 10:11:34.169 MyApp[89:307] Can't find filename default.mov in the app bundle
2010-09-13 10:11:34.948 MyApp[89:307] Device initialization: DeviceInfo = {"name":"iPhone","uuid":"548444a41eee3aec9dd66511e12e6a6b1b277a2a","platform":"iPhone","gap":"0.9.0","version":"4.0.2"};
2010-09-13 10:11:35.022 MyApp[89:307] Docs Path:/var/mobile/Applications/D887FEA7-0C56-4991-890F-E790361A9D64/Documents
2010-09-13 10:11:35.037 MyApp[89:307] Free space is 15497396224

And nothing else!!

Really annoying. Anybody know what might be happening here? I tried fiddling with a few settings in the Project Settings but that doesn't seem to have fixed it.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Regards
Nick

Answer (score 0):

Update - my problem. I had some external javascript which was crashing due to the way I was calling it from the HTML file. Weird that it only affected the iPhone/iPad device but not the simulators, but there you go....